# Apache POI XSSF Reads only the first row thought file is small

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

i am trying to read .xlsx file and iterate through all the rows of the file but it iterates only for the first line thoung there is data in send row of the file i also tried using  `getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` function but this also returns 1 , Despite having data in second row

here is my code

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
                System.out.println("FileInputStream Object created..! ");
                 /* Load workbook */
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
                System.out.println("XSSFWorkbook Object created..! ");
                /* Load worksheet */
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                System.out.println("XSSFSheet Object created..! ");
                int rowCount;
                rowCount= sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() ;
                System.out.println("total row: "+ rowCount);
```

[image: Hear is my .xlsx file data]

Comment: Where does your file come from? If you open it in Excel, and do a Save-As, does the file then work correctly?

Comment: actually  i have uploaded the file and then trying to read it , no it still  doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure that you uploaded file correctly? Try to open file on your local machine or use debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code bellow to get de Cells count:

```
 sheet.getLastCellNum()
```

Or use the code bellow to get de Rows count:

```
 sheet.getLastRowNum()
```

In both these you have to plus 1 because the index begin in 0.

Sometimes you want know the count event your sheet is empty so you can use:

```
Sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()
```